# JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'N' is found at position 0

Tags: json, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

I am new to JSON in SQL. I am getting the error "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'N' is found at position 0." while executing the below -

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(4000)
set @json1 = N'{"name":[{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}], "age":31, "city":"New York"}'
DECLARE @v NVARCHAR(4000)
set @v = CONCAT('N''',(SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.name')),'''')
--select @v as 'v'
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(@v,'$.FirstName')
```

the " select @v as 'v' " gives me

```
N'{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}'
```

But, using it in the last select statement gives me error.

```
DECLARE @v1 NVARCHAR(4000)
set @v1 = N'{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}'
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(@v1,'$.FirstName') as 'FirstName'
```

also works fine.

Comment: You don't appear to understand what that N is doing when you put it in front of a string. It is not meant to be an actual part of the string value, it simply means to convert the string to a NVARCHAR value instead of a VARCHAR.

Comment: i am getting this ..JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '1' is found at position 0.
any idea whats wrong..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding the `N`character in your `CONCAT` statement.

Try changing the line:

```
set @v = CONCAT('N''',(SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.name')),'''')
```

to:

```
set @v = CONCAT('''',(SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.name')),'''')
```

Comment: changing to set @v =(SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.name')) did the trick

Answer (score 18):

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or later there is build-in function `ISJSON` which validates that the string in the column is valid json.

Therefore you can do things like this:

```
SELECT 
  Name,
  JSON_VALUE(jsonCol, '$.info.address.PostCode') AS PostCode
FROM People
WHERE ISJSON(jsonCol) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

**JSON_VALUE** function **may** first be executed on **all** rows before applying the **where** clauses. It will depend on execution plan, it means that small things like having **top x** clause or **order by** may have a impact on that.

- It means that if your json data is invalid anywhere in that column(in the whole table), it will throw an error when the query is executed.
- So find and fix those invalid json formats first. For example if that column has a **' instead of "** in the Json payload it cannot be parsed and will cause the whole TSQL query to throw an error
- you can play with **top 10** and **order by** id to make the result set  smaller and find the row(s) which cause the json parser to break