# Search json array using SQL server JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Assuming a given json object:

```
{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}
```

SQL server has JSON_VALUE function that can be used in WHERE clause to match against a particular json element e.g.

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(columnName, $.info.address[1].town) = 'Belgrade'
```

The issue is that it requires an index. How do I search in all array elements specified by the path?

Comment: The path in JSON_VALUE or JSON_Query can't accept wildcards or expressions. You can't write `$.info.address[?(@.town='Belgrade')]`. Both of them return strings too. You need to convert the JSON string into rows with OPENJSON to query it

Answer (score 19):

You may try to use `OPENJSON` and a `WITH` clause (to specify columns and their types), and then search in all elements:

```
-- JSON
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = N'{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}'

-- Statement
SELECT Town
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.info.address') WITH (
   Town nvarchar(100) '$.town'
)
WHERE Town = N'Belgrade'
```

If the JSON content is stored in a table column, next approach is also an option:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   Id int,
   JsonData varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (Id, JsonData)
VALUES 
   (1, N'{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}'),
   (2, N'{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}'),
   (3, N'{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}')

-- Statement
SELECT DISTINCT d.Id
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData, '$.info.address') WITH (
   Town nvarchar(100) '$.town'
) j   
WHERE (j.Town = N'Belgrade') OR (j.Town = N'Paris')
```

Result:

```
-------
Id
-------
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 8):

The [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#PATH) in [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can't accept wildcards or expressions. You can't write `$.info.address[?(@.town='Belgrade')]` to search for a specific item.

Both functions return strings too so you can't use them to extract something that can be queried. You need to convert the JSON string into rows with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to query it, for example :

```
declare @json nvarchar(2000)='{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}'

select *
from openjson(@json, '$.info.address')
with (town varchar(200) '$.town')
where town='Belgrade'
```

This uses OPENJSON to extract the contents of the `address` array. It extracts the `town` attribute as a field and then uses it in `WHERE`.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to use OPENJSON with a table column, eg :

```
declare @json nvarchar(2000)='{"info":{"address":[{"town":"Belgrade"},{"town":"Paris"},{"town":"Madrid"}]}}'

DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
    id int identity primary key, 
    customer varchar(200),
    locations varchar(2000)
);

INSERT INTO @table (customer,locations)
VALUES ('AAA',@json);

SELECT *
FROM @table t CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.locations, '$.info.address')
                            WITH (town varchar(200) '$.town')
WHERE town='Belgrade';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck with `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character` error add SQL expression to check that the column contains valid json string.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73632440/9547346)