# JSON response file provided by Google Geocode is having duplicate column types, and showing error "Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 163"

Tags: sql, google-geocoding-api

The response file from Google - Sample one.

From this response I am trying to fetch latitude and longitude from json response. But it is throwing this error:

> Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 163
> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'r' is found at position 1.

I think it is because of the types column duplicate in the `.json` file response. Can we ask google to provide as type1 and type2.

As I will be doing automation logic over this piece of code. Your suggestions and guidance will be highly appreciated.

Here's the JSON and code:

```
{
    "results" : [
       {
          "address_components" : [
             {
                "long_name" : "1600",
                "short_name" : "1600",
                "types" : [ "street_number" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
                "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                "types" : [ "route" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Mountain View",
                "short_name" : "Mountain View",
                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
                "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "California",
                "short_name" : "CA",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "United States",
                "short_name" : "US",
                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "94043",
                "short_name" : "94043",
                "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
             }
          ],
          "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
          "geometry" : {
             "location" : {
                "lat" : 37.4267861,
                "lng" : -122.0806032
             },
             "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
             "viewport" : {
                "northeast" : {
                   "lat" : 37.4281350802915,
                   "lng" : -122.0792542197085
                },
                "southwest" : {
                   "lat" : 37.4254371197085,
                   "lng" : -122.0819521802915
                }
             }
          },
          "place_id" : "ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE",
          "plus_code" : {
             "compound_code" : "CWC8+R3 Mountain View, California, United States",
             "global_code" : "849VCWC8+R3"
          },
          "types" : [ "street_address" ]
       }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max) = N'{
    "results" : [
       {
          "address_components" : [
             {
                "long_name" : "1600",
                "short_name" : "1600",
                "types" : [ "street_number" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
                "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                "types" : [ "route" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Mountain View",
                "short_name" : "Mountain View",
                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
                "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "California",
                "short_name" : "CA",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "United States",
                "short_name" : "US",
                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "94043",
                "short_name" : "94043",
                "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
             }
          ],
          "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
          "geometry" : {
             "location" : {
                "lat" : 37.4267861,
                "lng" : -122.0806032
             },
             "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
             "viewport" : {
                "northeast" : {
                   "lat" : 37.4281350802915,
                   "lng" : -122.0792542197085
                },
                "southwest" : {
                   "lat" : 37.4254371197085,
                   "lng" : -122.0819521802915
                }
             }
          },
          "place_id" : "ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE",
          "plus_code" : {
             "compound_code" : "CWC8+R3 Mountain View, California, United States",
             "global_code" : "849VCWC8+R3"
          },
          "types" : [ "street_address" ]
       }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}';

SELECT * 
FROM OpenJson(@json)
WITH 
    (Address NVARCHAR(200) '$results.formatted_address' ,
     latitude nvarchar(max) '$results.geometry.location.lat', 
     longitude nvarchar(max) '$results.geometry.location.lng') AS my_json;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is the error related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782937/18422887